# Open second package in first package

Tags: android

I've two packages naming sendsms and messagebox. both the packages are having different xml files. I've created a button in class of package messagebox as:

```
if (v == btnSent)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, SendSms.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
            finish();
    }
```

when i click on this button it will open the code that is written in SendSms of package sendsms and my manifest file is like:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.messagebox.MessageBox"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="sendsms.SendSms"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="sendsms.SendSms" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
```

Comment: so what is your problem ?

Comment: what do you mean by "open the code"? what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.messagebox.MessageBox"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".sendsms.SendSms"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".sendsms.SendSms" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
```

put dot in second activity declaration of mainfest.